# Is there such a thing as sacramental wine in the Faith of the Seven?

Tags: game-of-thrones

To me it seems the Faith of the Seven from *Game of Thrones* has some commonalities with the medieval Catholic Church. Do any of the FotS's rituals involve sacred wine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No usage of sacramental wine has been depicted so far in any of the books and in neither of the two TV shows.**

That being said, you are correct that the Faith of the Seven is based on the medieval Catholic church - that has been stated by George R.R. Martin himself:

> George R. R. Martin based the Faith of the Seven on the medieval
> Catholic Church, although it borrows from other elements as well.
> The Faith's central doctrine that there is one god who has seven
> aspects—the Father, the Mother, the Maiden, the Crone, the Smith, the
> Warrior, and the Stranger—is based on the Catholic belief that there
> is one God who has three aspects: the Father, the Son, and the Holy
> Ghost.
>
> Martin has also stated that the amount of power the Faith has,
> similarly to the Catholic Church, in great part depends on who was
> chosen as High Septon or Pope. The Faith Militant is loosely
> based on crusading orders, e.g. Knights Templar and Knights
> Hospitaller.

Martin talks a bit more on the seven aspects vs. the Holy Trinity relation in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1wiqdd1K4A).

There are also other similar elements, like the facts that the [septons](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Septon) use a censer and incense and that the High Septon wears a crown (likewise to popes wearing a [tiara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_tiara) in the past).

Taking this into account there is a possibility that wine as an element of a liturgy may appear in one of the future books, TV shows or episodes of *House of the Dragon*.